# can not open the sqlite database in user-selected folder

Tags: c#, uwp

below is my code to open a database in a user-selected folder

```
SqliteConnection db;
public async Task<string> openDatabase(String databaseFilename)
{

    db = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={databaseFilename}");
    await db.OpenAsync();
    return null;
}
//...
 


var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();//must-use broker in UWP
StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
string encryptedUserSelectedFolderString = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);


//...

StorageFolder fd = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(encryptedUserSelectedFolderString);//user-selected folder
var t = await fd.TryGetItemAsync("data.data");//sqlite in the folder
if (t != null)  
{
   db.openDatabase(Path.Combine(fd.Path,"data.data"));//this line causes app freezing
}
```

it reports the error:

> unable to open the database file

...but the same code:

```
StorageFolder fd = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path);  
var t = await fd.TryGetItemAsync("data.data");
db.openDatabase(Path.Combine(fd.Path, "data.data"));//open database correctly
```

...can open the database in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` **without** any problem

Just wondering if there is a special requirement to open the database in the user-selected folder?

--------------------------------------------------updated question

my code to open a png file in the sub folder of the user-selected folder

```
Task<StorageFolder> folder = folderForBookmark(encryptedUserSelectedFolderString);            
StorageFolder bbb =await folder;            
StorageFile aaa = await  bbb.GetFileAsync(  "subfolder\\1.png");            
IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await aaa.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);            
//*create Bitmap from filestream            
BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();            
bmpImage.SetSource(fileStream);            
//load bitmap into image-control            
aImage.Source = bmpImage;
```

it works! it can load the image file

Comment: I have used a broker to select the folder, so I can copy or rename the database file in the folder, but still can not open it

Comment: UWP apps are sandboxed and any attempt to open files outside of their claim will be denied.  You need the _broad filesystem_ right if you  want to access any location.  Even if `encryptedUserSelectedFolderString` points to `My Documents` you need the **Documents** right.  If the _"bridge"_ is native non-UWP code it probably doesn't prove much that it can copy the file if the destination folder is outside your UWP domain

Comment: but why I can rename the database file?

Comment: In the Debugger, what is the value of `databaseFilename` inside the call to `openDatabase()`?

Comment: c:\\users\\mypc\\Desktop\\tem\\data.data  and c:\\users\\mypc\\Desktop\\tem is the user-selected folder

Comment: before this case, I think I can process any file under the user-selected folder c:\\users\\mypc\\Desktop\\tem, include copy rename and open them. I am sure that copy files to this folder and  rename the files in the folder have no any problem.

Comment: I see the path involves the user's **Desktop** which requires [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations).  I don't understand why you keep bringing up file rename.  UWP apps are not like any other Windows app

Comment: I confused by UWP, while on macOS, I have all rights to open the files in the user-selected folder and its sub folder

Comment: I think you need to read up on UWP

Comment: I try to open the image files in the folder without any problem, it looks like only the database file can not be opened, so I guess the line db = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={databaseFilename}"); causes this happen

Comment: @MickyD please refer to my updated question